# Rundeck reverse proxy behind Nginx

Tags: proxy, reverse, rundeck

I have configured reverse proxy for Rundeck behind Nginx. Below is the Rundeck.conf which is placed in the path /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

```
ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
## server configuration
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80 ;
    server_name ~(?<repo>.+)\.pilot1 pilot1;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }
    ## Application specific logs
    ## access_log /var/log/nginx/pilot1.ci1.peapod.com-access.log timing;
    ## error_log /var/log/nginx/pilot1.ci1.peapod.com-error.log;
# rewrite ^/$ /rundeck/menu/home redirect;
   rewrite ^/rundeck/?(/rundeck)?$ /rundeck/menu/home redirect;
   chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    client_max_body_size 0;

location ^~ /rundeck/ {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:4440;
        proxy_read_timeout  900;
}
}
```

Reverse proxy works fine when I browse and login to Rundeck.But when I click log out the redirection to the login page exposes the port:4440
as below
LOGIN----> pilot1/rundeck redirects to pilot1/rundeck/menu/home  (works fine)
Logout---> pilot1:4440/rundeck/user/loggedout

I do not want the port to be exposed. How do i fix this issue?

Comment: Did you set framework.rundeck.url and grails.serverURL to use https? Check `framework.rundeck.url` in `/etc/rundeck/framework.properties` and `grails.serverURL` in `/etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I had to do:

In NGINX config under an appropriate 'server' section set up a location:

```
  location /rundeck/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4440;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

Rundeck config:

```
sed -i "/^grails.serverURL/c grails.serverURL = ${RUNDECK_URL}" /etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties
sed -i "/^framework.server.url/c framework.server.url = ${RUNDECK_URL}" /etc/rundeck/framework.properties
sed -i '/^RDECK_JVM="$RDECK_JVM/ s/"$/ -Dserver.web.context=\/rundeck"/' /etc/rundeck/profile
```

where `RUNDECK_URL` should point to you NGINX ip (dns name) so http://my-nginx.com/rundeck

Comment: Just a few details :
1] It seems that "server.web.context" parameter doesn't exist anymore (Rundeck 3.2.8), the new one is "server.contextPath".
2] You should not change the /etc/rundeck/profile as it can be overwritten on Rundeck upgrade. As the documentation suggests, you should use /etc/default/rundeckd (on DEB install) with this content :

`RDECK_JVM_OPTS="-Dserver.contextPath=/rundeck"`

Documentation : https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/system-properties.html

Comment: A portion of this should not be followed as `/etc/rundeck/profile`, can will be updated on upgrade.  save to `/etc/defaults/rundeckd`